# How do I decode a one-hot encoded NumPy matrix in a fast manner using vectorization?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, one-hot-encoding

Given an image matrix of shape `(height, width)` with values in the `uint8` range, which was one-hot encoded (converted to categorical) to a shape of `(height, width, n)` where n is the number of possible categories, 3 in this instance resulting in a shape of `(height, width, 3)`, I would like to undo the categorical conversion and get the original shape of `(height, width)`. The following solution works, but could be made much faster:

```
def decode(image):
    image = image

    height = image.shape[0]
    width = image.shape[1]

    decoded_image = numpy.ndarray(shape=(height, width), dtype=numpy.uint8)

    for i in range(0, height):
        for j in range(0, width):
            decoded_image[i][j] = numpy.argmax(image[i][j])

    return decoded_image
```

I would like a solution, using `NumPy vectorization`, without the need for a slower Python `for loop`.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to do a reduction over the last dimension of your array, in particular a `numpy.argmax`. Fortunately, this numpy function accepts an `axis` keyword, so you should be able to do the same in just one call:

```
decoded_image = numpy.argmax(image, axis=2)
```

Comment: Thank you. I had not realized that I could specify the axis; this is an elegant solution.